# How to load properties file in JBOSS 6 from other place

Tags: java, jboss, application-server

I want to change location of all properties file but I do not know where to change in JBOSS 6 for new path, I am asking it because I am new in JBOSS.

it uses some default path, for example for "com/test/configuration/main" path is modules/com/test/configuration/main

but I want to load all property from say c:\prop_files\

for it i have tried to modified module.xml

```html
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.test.configuration">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="c:\props_files\"/>
</resources>
</module>
```

but it is giving me exception

```html
org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Failed to add resource root 'C:\props_files' at path 'C:\props_files'
```

please suggest.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Which properties file ?

Comment: my application related property file for example i have app and it uses myapp.properties and i deployed it to jboss

Comment: set  JBOSS_MODULEPATH=$JBOSS_HOME/modules:/path/to/my/modules
 
also make sure that what is the name of variable, it was changed from MODULE_PATH to MODULEPATH and is now JBOSS_MODULEPATH(7.1.0+) as other two ware clashing with some other sofware..

or look at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/170826 if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add the path in your configuration file ( standalone.xml/domain.xml).
For example in standalone.xml (it goes after `</extensions>` and before `<management>` tag):

```
<paths>
    <path name="my.home.dir" path="C:\Users\elvis\Downloads"/>
</paths>
```

You can do that via CLI as well:

```
./bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9999
/path=my.home.dir:add(path=C:\\Users\\elvis\\Downloads)
```

---

Then you reference the path in your application, for example:

```
String path = System.getProperty("my.home.dir") + propertiesFileName;
Properties props = new Properties();
URL url = new URL(path);
props.load(url.openStream());
```